# first char is not stored in a string object using getline() function of string header in c++

Tags: c++

```
string nums;

int main() {
  int cases;
  scanf("%d", &cases);
  while (cases--) {
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, nums);
    cout << nums << endl;
  }
}
```

input example

```
3

1 2 1 2 1

2 3 4 1 2 5 10 50 3 50

3 5 2 7 1 7 5 2 8 9 1 25 15 8 3 1 38 45 8 1
```

I expect right result below

```
1 2 1 2 1

2 3 4 1 2 5 10 50 3 50

3 5 2 7 1 7 5 2 8 9 1 25 15 8 3 1 38 45 8 1
```

However, the output is that

```
1 2 1 2 1

 3 4 1 2 5 10 50 3 50

 5 2 7 1 7 5 2 8 9 1 25 15 8 3 1 38 45 8 1
```

I don't know what the reason is. I clearly use `cin.ignore()` to flush the buffer.
Why is the first char removed ?

Comment: `scanf` is C, `std::cin` and `std::getline` are C++.  Pick one and go with it.

Comment: Please explain more about " I clearly use cin.ignore() to flush the buffer."

Comment: `std::getline` reads up to and _including_ the newline character, so there is no need to ignore it.

Comment: "I clearly use cin.ignore() to flush the buffer" – no, that's not what `ignore` does.

Comment: To input value in the 'cases', i typed enter. Therefore, it is remained in the cin. Using cin.ignore(), it is discarded from that.

Comment: is there any problem because of cin.ignore()??

Comment: i think that using cin.ignore() before input nums never be a problem? is that right?

Comment: You need to be careful with `eofbit` state. After `scanf`, `ignore` is fine because the `'\n'` remains in the input buffer, but it is less clear what effect that has after `getline` as nothing remains in `stdin` which will cause `ignore` (having reached the default delimiter `EOF` before discarding any characters) to set `eofbit` (at which point you type additional input)

Comment: @조해인 you don't need to `cin.ignore()` in this case, and it's causing your first number to be discarded hence your original problem. Don't use it here.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. key is the eofbit. i have to conosider it. thanks guys. i know what is the problem and the reason to cause it

Answer (score 2):

Just put the line `cin.ignore();` outside the `while` loop:

Following is corrected code. See it working [here](https://ideone.com/ZRP2sI):

```
string nums;

int main() 
{
    int cases;
    scanf("%d", &cases);//Better if you use `cin>>cases;` here, just for sake of C++.
    cin.ignore();
    while (cases--) 
    {
        getline(cin, nums);
        cout << nums <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your `cases` to 0 just in case a user enters an invalid input for an integer type like a character or something.  You should prefer to use `std::cin` for user input in C++ like I stated in the comments section. You can skip the `\n` newline character after your initial input by calling `get()`. It's serving the same purpose as you were trying to achieve with `ignore()`. `while(cases--)` is a bit weird to look at but I get what you're going for.  You can declare your `string nums` inside the loop since you're overwriting it every iteration anyway. The reason you do not need to use `std::cin.ignore()` in this code is because `std::getline` reads everything including the newline character from console input. This code should do exactly what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int cases(0);  ///< initialize in case user enters text
    (std::cin >> cases).get(); ///< use std::cin in C++; get() to skip `\n`
    while (cases--) ///< is that really what you want?
    {
        std::string nums; ///< nums only needed locally
        std::getline(std::cin, nums); ///< reads whole line + '\n'
        std::cout << nums << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i also know that. i agree with your think that to declare variables in main is better habit than outside. However, that does not make this problem.

Comment: @조해인 If you read the rest of my comments in the code, I think this does answer your question. You don't need to call `cin.ignore()` in your case.